# How to get the list of project selected in the package explorer or project explorer?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to get the projects selected in the project or package explorer. 
If i select a project **Hello** in package explorer then I **should get Hello as the return** value.
If I select **two projects, Hello and World** project then I should get a return value **containing Hello, World** in it.
I want a java code for the above. And I am doing this in eclipse plugin.

Comment: Whoever downvoted the question, please read the entire question. I hope this forum is not just for Hi-Fi questions!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `ISelectionListener` and register it at the `ISelectionService`, then you'll get all selections of all views and editors - not only from package explorer.

See

- http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-WorkbenchSelections/article.html
- http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_make_a_view_respond_to_selection_changes_in_another_view%3F

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I got the exact way here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6892294/eclipse-plugin-how-to-get-the-path-to-the-currently-selected-project